How to perform BLS12-381 verification on Polygon?
Does Polygon standard or the ZKEVM version have precompile to achieve this. In Polygon ZKEVM I believe requires BLS pairings so does it mean it has a precompile?
In the Etrog upgrade they added ecAdd, ecMul, and ecPairing. Can these be used for BLS12-381 verification?
